How do I keep php from escaping the backslash in my unicode string?
I have a laravel 11 application using PHP 8.3, and I have a string stored in my postgres db in a text column that looks like this: We’re excited to have you join the team today! \u1F60A.
I'm using the AWS SDK for End User SMS messaging, their PinpointSmsVoiceV2 API, to send text messages to our employees about various HR/onboarding deadlines.
The AWS SDK will give me an error about invalid parameters if I try to submit a raw emoji like . I talked to AWS customer support and they confirmed that it needed to be submitted as unicode like \u1F60A.
The problem is, it seems like PHP really does not want to allow an unescaped backslash in their strings. No matter what I try to do do, it keeps adding a second backslash, escaping the intended one, so I end up with \\u1F60A.
My goal is to be able to pull the string from the DB and submit it to the API. In between pulling it from the DB and the API, I have tried using regex to remove a slash, I've tried using stripslashes(), I've tried escaping the escape char, I've tried a bunch of stuff suggested by ChatGPT and Claude and Discord to no avail.
The closest I've come is this. https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax
If I hardcode the string directly into a variable like this this $message = <<<EOT \u{01f418} EOT; it works, and the AWS sdk happily sends the emoji.
The thing is, I don't want to hardcode the string, I want to pull it from my DB. This is how I'm currently doing it
$marketSettings = RecruitmentMessagingSettings::where('organization_id', request()->user()->organization_id)
            ->where('market', 'TEST - MARKET')
            ->first();

$message = $marketSettings->in_person_message;

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

try to use double quotes, pass it to parameter. Something like "We’re excited to have you join the team today! $whateveryourparameteris"

PHP strings are binary, backslashes don't pose any issue. But you need to distinguish between actual string contents and different plain text representations of those values, such as string literals in PHP code: https://3v4l.org/XWh0O#v8.3.11

Here’s a strategy you can use:

Store and Retrieve the String as a Unicode Literal
If the string is stored in the database in the format \u1F60A, you want to interpret it as a Unicode character. You can convert this string into an actual Unicode character using a PHP function.

Convert the String to a Unicode Character
You can write a small function that takes the string with Unicode escape sequences (like \u1F60A) and converts it to the actual character.


Here's an example of how to do that:
function decode_unicode_escape_sequences($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($matches) {
        return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $matches[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
    }, $string);
}

// Fetch the message from the database
$marketSettings = RecruitmentMessagingSettings::where('organization_id', request()->user()->organization_id)
    ->where('market', 'TEST - MARKET')
    ->first();

// Convert the Unicode escape sequences to actual characters
$message = decode_unicode_escape_sequences($marketSettings->in_person_message);

// Now you can safely use $message with the AWS SDK


Sending the Converted Message via AWS SDK
Once the string is converted, it can be passed to the AWS SDK without issues since the string is now in the correct format.

